# JQueryUI - droppable only one at a time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using `jQueryUI` for `draggable` and `droppable`.

If I drop one element in droppable area and again if try to drop 2nd object. First dropped element should automatically remove and moved to draggable area.

> Basically, only one element should be in droppable area.

[**Here fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6auhhjxc/)

[image]

As soon as droppable area has more than 1 element. It should just remove last element. If added one more element. Droppable area can't have more than 1 object.

code:

```
$("#dvSource img").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    //refreshPositions: true,
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
        if ($.ui.ddmanager.drop(ui.helper.data("draggable"), event)) {
                console.log($("#dvDest img").length);   
        }
        else {
            //alert(image + " not dropped.");
        }
    }
});
$("#dvDest").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if ($("#dvDest img").length == 0) {
            $("#dvDest").html("");
        }
        ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
                $("#dvDest").append(ui.draggable);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Difficult to explain.. I hope.. This gif can explain better..

Comment: So, on first drag'n drop, no change. On second, you want the dragged item to swap with the existing item. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not fabulous with animations, but here is one way to do it.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6auhhjxc/5/

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#dvSource img").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
      if ($.ui.ddmanager.drop(ui.helper.data("draggable"), event)) {
        console.log($("#dvDest img").length);
      }
    }
  });
  $("#dvDest").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if ($("#dvDest img").length === 0) {
        $("#dvDest").html("");
      } else {
        $("#dvDest img:first").hide(600, function() {
          $(this).appendTo("#dvSource");
        }).show(600);
      }
      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      $("#dvDest").append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
```

In the drop, you already had a good check. So if there are `img` elements in the destination when you `drop`, You will want to append the drop and then append the first element back to the source.

I added some simple `.hide()` and `.show()` animations to make it fancy. I also adjusted each image, so you can see that the right item is moving back.

I suspect there is way to animate the the return in some fashion, that's just not in my bag of tricks. But this should get you there if that is in your bag.

**Update after Comments**

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6auhhjxc/7/

I found an issue in your draggable code that kept throwing an error. I removed it.

Since we destroy/create draggables over and over, I made a function to help do this. The drag/drop adds a bunch of styling to retain positioning so I drop that and the `class` when I pass the `img` back to the source.

**jQuery**

```
function makeDrag(el) {
  // Pass me an object, and I will make it draggable
  el.draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
}
$(function() {

  makeDrag($("#dvSource img"));

  $("#dvDest").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if ($("#dvDest img").length === 0) {
        $("#dvDest").html("");
      } else {
        $("#dvDest img:first").hide(600, function() {
          $(this).removeAttr("class");
          $(this).removeAttr("style");
          $(this).appendTo("#dvSource");
        }).show(600, function() {
          makeDrag($(this));
        });
      }
      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      ui.draggable.draggable("destroy");
      $("#dvDest").append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
```

The code in your `stop` that was causing an issue:

```
if ($.ui.ddmanager.drop(ui.helper.data("draggable"), event)) {
    console.log($("#dvDest img").length);
}
```

I switched to the uncompressed version, and the error thrown was:

> TypeError: draggable is undefined
>
> $.each( ( $.ui.ddmanager.droppables[ draggable.options.scope ] || [] ).slice(), ...

The section of code for this is:

```
    $.each( ( $.ui.ddmanager.droppables[ draggable.options.scope ] || [] ).slice(), function() {

        if ( !this.options ) {
            return;
        }
        if ( !this.options.disabled && this.visible && $.ui.intersect( draggable, this, this.options.tolerance, event ) ) {
            dropped = this._drop.call( this, event ) || dropped;
        }

        if ( !this.options.disabled && this.visible && this.accept.call( this.element[ 0 ], ( draggable.currentItem || draggable.element ) ) ) {
            this.isout = true;
            this.isover = false;
            this._deactivate.call( this, event );
        }

    });
```

In the minimized code, this was `t`, but the issue is the same. When you passed `ui.helper.data("draggable")` to `$.ui.ddmanager.drop()`, the value was `null` or `undefined`. The reason for this, in the scope of your script, was that `ui.helper` did not have a `data-draggable` attribute.

Again, it was not clear what the intended action was there, so I simply removed it.

Comment: This is perfect. But, Once I drag n drop and again I want to do same drag and drop. Second time elements don't drag and also UI library is giving error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`.  I tried to solve it. But you know better than me.

Comment: You didn't include that in your post. Will check it in a bit.

Comment: @locateganesh updated my answer. Works as desired: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6auhhjxc/7/

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much. I will try to understand your logic of code completely.

Comment: @Twisty, May I ask you to have a look at a droppable related question here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51301758/jquery-droppable-allow-only-one-item-to-be-dropped-on-an-element-and-then-make ?